# Get-ScheduledTask status in an array

Tags: powershell

I would like to get

```
Get-ScheduledTask
```

status in an Array. I would like all ON to be in the Array.

Comment: As others have said, the command alread returns an array '$tasks = Get-ScheduledTask;$tasks.gettype().fullname' results in 'System.Object[]'

Can you clarify what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if I understnand you correctly, but this should do the job:

```
$foo = (Get-ScheduledTask|where State -eq Running)
```

Change `Running` to whatever you need: `Running`, `Ready`, `Disabled`

Comment: you can omit the parenthesis ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The [Get-ScheduledTask](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=287549) cmdlet already returns an `array` of `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance#Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler/MSFT_ScheduledTask`. To filter them, you have to use the [Where-Object](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113423) cmdlet:

```
$tasks = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object State -eq Running
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "ON" you mean not disabled, I believe this is the solution.

```
$results = Get-ScheduledTask | Where-Object { $_.State -ne 'Disabled' }
```

The type of `$results` is `System.Object[]`